# Is there a way to log a debug message in saltstack out of an .sls or a .jinja file?

Tags: salt-stack

Is there a way to log a custom debug message in saltstack out of an .sls or a .jinja file? i.e. something like:

```
{% salt.log_message("Entering...") %}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to print. Please give some more context. In simple case - what you can do is smth like:  
     {% set foo="bar" %}
      debug_print: 
        cmd.run:
          - name: "echo {{foo}}"
This will execute `echo` dumping the content of `foo` . Sorry for the code block, my markdown-foo is too bad :)

Comment: You can also try [test state](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.test.html#module-salt.states.test)

Answer (score 12):

This was added as [a feature in 2017.7.0](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#logs):

> Yes, in Salt, one is able to debug a complex Jinja template using the
>   logs. For example, making the call:
>
> ```
> {%- do salt.log.error('testing jinja logging') -%}
> ```
>
> Will insert the following message in the minion logs:
>
> ```
> 2017-02-01 01:24:40,728 [salt.module.logmod][ERROR   ][3779] testing jinja logging
> ```

Answer (score 11):

Add a state using `test.nop` and add things you want to inspect as arguments to it.

The use

```
salt-call -l debug state.apply yourslsfile test=True
```

or

```
salt-call --output=yaml state.show_sls yourslsfile
```

to check the result.

For example:

debug.sls

```
test:
  test.nop:
  - user: {{ grains.username }}
  - nested:
      foo: bar
```

Here is the result of `state.show_sls`

```
local:
  test:
    test:
    - user: ian
    - nested:
        foo: bar
    - nop
    - order: 10000
    __sls__: !!python/unicode dotfiles
    __env__: base
```

It is better to setup a standalong environment to test states, like [this](https://github.com/doitian/salt-standalong)